# How to put a text label below the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage just like the online shopping .Here i've created images to be displayed inside the div.I used span to put a zoom button on the image. 
Ain't knowing how to put a box right below it which displays the cost and the name.
I tried putting div inside it but it is not working.

```
    ------------
    |          |
    |  image   |
    |          |
    |--        |
    |  |Zoom   |
    ------------
    | label    |
    ------------
```

I need the label to be placed right below the div.Could anyone help me by which i can achieve it.

```
<div class="box photo lefttooltip" title="Sample Text" >
    <div  id="leftimage">
        <img id="orn<%=j%>" class="drag ornthumb1" align="center" src="<%=itms[j]%>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span id="leftzoom" onClick="zoominProduct('<%=itms[j]%>')">
        <img class="zoomin" src="jqe13/image/left_zoom_hover.png" title="Zoomin">
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
#leftimage { 
    height:80px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    position:relative;
}

#leftimage img {  
    max-height: 98%;
    max-width: 98%;
    padding: 1%; 
    line-height:none;
}

#lt_scroller .box #leftzoom img {
    line-height:normal; 
    padding:2px;
}

#lt_scroller .box #leftzoom {
    width:auto; 
    height:16px; 
    float:left;
    top:-16px;  
    left:2px; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:1000; 
    line-height:normal;
}

#lt_scroller .box #leftzoom:hover { }

.imgcontainer #leftzoom { 
    display:none;
}

#leftzoom img { 
    opacity:.3;
}

.ornthumb1 {
    width: auto;
    height:100px;
    //float:left;
}
```

Comment: Where's your current CSS?

Comment: Please provide your CSS

Comment: Where is the part for label in your code?

Comment: i've put the css ..please check the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Just add your div below your codes,

```
<div class="box photo lefttooltip" title="Sample Text" >    
<div  id="leftimage"><img id="orn<%=j%>" class="drag ornthumb1" 
align="center" src="<%=itms[j]%>" alt="" /></div>    
<span id="leftzoom" onClick="zoominProduct('<%=itms[j]%>')">        
<img class="zoomin" src="jqe13/image/left_zoom_hover.png" title="Zoomin"></span>    
</div>    
--------------- add here ---------------------------
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class=""> Your label contnet here</div>
```

Comment: thanx but..i dont get the div attached to the above div

Comment: <div style="clear:both;"></div>    
<div class=""> Your label content here</div>    add before closing your main div "</div>"

Answer (score 2):

hope this fiddle helps [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitladhania/Qa7Aa/)

```
<div class=wrapper>
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="cost">
        cost: $4.99
    </div>
</div>
```